# Conditional data type conversion for parameters in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I read about [Cast and Convert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191530.aspx) functions of SQL Server, but I have a little different requirement. I want to declare all the stored procedure parameters as `varchar` to eliminate most of the conversion code that is needed in C# while adding parameters with `AddWithValue` method.

I want to put as much code in the database itself as possible to reduce front-end code. My stored procedure contains `INSERT` and `UPDATE` queries. I want to convert the data type of parameters in queries itself or in any other better way out. CAST function works well for conversion but what if I also want to pass NULL if the parameter has no value?

For example:

```
@Udate varchar(10),
@Uamount varchar(50)

INSERT INTO table (Name, Udate, Uamount) 
  VALUES (@Name, Cast(Udate As DateTime), Cast(Uamount As Decimal)
```

The disadvantage of using `CAST` in query itself is that the readability of query becomes poor with many `CAST` functions. Where else I can convert the data types and how to check null values as well?

Comment: I don't think this approach is a very good idea. Just because you want to avoid *unnecessary* typing in your call in C#, you basically make everything a `varchar` and then `CAST` it back..... seems pretty stupid to me. If an item of data is a NUMERIC - represent it as a NUMERIC all the way! Don't cast it twice - first from numeric to string in your C# code, and then back from string to numeric in your stored procedure. Casting **always** costs time, and in cases like with dates, formatting issues might also arise! **DON'T DO IT!!**

Comment: Where else? You can use triggers for insert and update in which you can do all your conversions. And your query will remain simple and transparent.

Comment: I think you are going to have more problems getting the CAST statements to work in the stored procedure than you would by just converting them in the first place in your C# code and passing the correct type.

Comment: What's the problem with passing the values in as their actual types? You'll have to convert them to strings in C# anyways, won't you? And casting everything from strings in the DB would actually slow down your query. There's a processing cost associated with type conversion even if it may not be noticeable.

Comment: Quite honestly: typing `cmd.Parameters.Add("@MyParamName, SqlDbType.Int).Value = 42` is really not that much more than `.AddWithvalue` - plus, if you **explicitly specify** the data type to ADO.NET, you're sure it will be correct - with `AddWithValue`, ADO.NET makes a guess - which works fine most of the time, but it **can fail miserably** ..... don't do it - **explicitly tell** ADO.NET what type you have, and pass it **as that specific type** - don't just cast everything to string

Comment: See [Stringly-typed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349378/new-programming-jargon-you-coined/2444303#2444303)

Comment: I have concerns with handling NULL. What if the Textbox value is null? Than I need to use ?: which makes it long enough.

Answer (score 0):

I think, this url might help you.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy6y35y8.aspx